# Laravel edit form

Tags: php, forms, frameworks, laravel

just wondering how edit details once you've saved them onto your database?

Like I want to edit Name and Contact details from the browser?

So far I have placeholders or stuff that I want to edit.

```
<ul class="no-bullet">
    <li>Full Name: {{ $providerName }} {{ $providerSurname }}</li>
    <li>Email Adress: {{ $providerEmail }}</li>
    <li>Contact Number:</li>
    <li>Company:</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="small radius button">Edit Details</a>
```

Comment: This is perhaps the most Geordie question I’ve seen on Stack Overflow, like.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind a database model to your form:

```
Form::model($provider, array('route' => array('provider.update', $user->id)))
```

Laravel will automagically fill out your inputs with database data.

This this is could be your `accountEdit` view:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ Form::model($provider, array('route' => array('provider.update', $provider->id))) }}
            {{ Form::label('providerName', 'Full Name:')) }}
            {{ Form::text('providerName') }}
            {{ Form::text('providerSurname') }}

            {{ Form::label('providerEmail', 'E-Mail Address') }}
            {{ Form::text('providerEmail') }}

            {{ Form::submit('Send this form!') }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </body>
</html>
```

This could be your route

```
Route::get('edit', function() { 
    $provider = Provider::find(1); 

    return View::make('accountEdit')->with(compact('provider'));
});   

Route::get('provider/update', array('as'=>'provider.update', function() { 

    dd(Input::all())

});
```

Comment: I should make a new file for the html form bit?

Sorry, I'm just using the route file not controller. Also I changed the User file in the model as Provider as I call my "users" as "providers" instead.

Route::get('edit', function()
{
$providerID = Provider::find(1);
return View::make('accountEdit')->with(compact('providerID'));;

});

Comment: Edited to provide some more clues and support your model and your route.

Comment: I get this error though

Unable to generate a URL for the named route "provider.update"

Comment: You need a POST route you are using in your form. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ Form::model($provider, array('route' => array('provider.update', $provider->id))) }}
```

using the code above it doesn't autofill the fields in my edit form. However when I removed the first array like this the form has filled with data.

```
{{ Form::model($provider, array('provider.update', $provider->id)) }}
```